# I need a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create a function that in cm_customers$rt table to verify to resident clients if the TAX_NUMBER is 13 digits otherwise need show the list  to the screen, i was create juste select but i need a function,please help me

```
select  TAX_NUMBER,RESIDENT
from cm_customers$rt
WHERE length (TAX_NUMBER) =13 and resident = 'Y'
;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So what's stopping you from turning this into a function? All you need to know is what datatype the client expects - ref cursor or nested table?

Comment: i just start to learn pl/sql i dont know how to create a function :D

Comment: I'm intrigued. You're doing a course which doesn't give you any introductory teaching or point you to (say) [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370) but instead suggests you ask a random bunch of strangers on StackOverflow? I hope you're not paying much for this teaching.

Comment: i dont pay nothing ,i just studing

Comment: Well check out the Oracle docs I linked to They're free too :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tax
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    V_tax_number  int;

BEGIN
    SELECT tax_number 
    INTO V_tax_number
    FROM E_EMP
    WHERE LENGTH(tax_number ) < 13 
                 AND residence_type = 'Y';
    RETURN V_tax_number;

END;
```